# How can I access environment varibale declared in .env file from .yarnrc.yaml file?

Tags: yarn-v2

I have an environment variable declared in .env file which looks like this

```
 BUF_REGISTRY_TOKEN=ZZZZZZZ
```

Now here is my .yarnrc.yaml file,

```
nodeLinker: node-modules
plugins:
  - path: .yarn/plugins/@yarnpkg/plugin-workspace-tools.cjs
  spec: "@yarnpkg/plugin-workspace-tools"
- path: .yarn/plugins/@yarnpkg/plugin-typescript.cjs
  spec: "@yarnpkg/plugin-typescript"

npmScopes:
  buf:
    npmAuthToken: ${BUF_REGISTRY_TOKEN}
    npmRegistryServer: "https://buf.build/gen/npm/v1/"

yarnPath: .yarn/releases/yarn-3.6.1.cjs
```

When I try to run yarn install command, I get the following error.

```
 Usage Error: Environment variable not found (BUF_REGISTRY_TOKEN) in /Users/zzz/my-project/.yarnrc.yml
```

How can I get access to the BUF-REGISTRY_TOKEN variable?

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a bit tricky as Yarn itself doesn't consider .env files (although it looks like [there is already a fix](https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/pull/5531), probably coming with Yarn 4).

Having said that, you could write a wrapper script, which sources the .env file before running yarn.

### Plugin-based solution for registry authentication

For the specific task of setting an authentication header for a registry, there is another solution, though: write a minimal plugin with a `getNpmAuthenticationHeader` hook.

We are currently using the code below in one of our projects (adapted for your case hopefully without mistakes).
For your target registry, it first tries to get the token from the actual environment and if that doesn't succeed, it loads an .env file, parses it and extracts the value from there.

#### .yarn/plugin-env-npm.js

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'plugin-env-npm',
  factory: require => ({
    hooks: {
      async getNpmAuthenticationHeader(currentHeader, registry, {ident}){
        // only trigger for specific scope
        if (!ident || ident.scope !== 'buf') {
          return currentHeader
        }

        // try getting token from process.env
        let bufEnv = process.env.BUF_REGISTRY_TOKEN
        // alternatively, try to find it in .env
        if (!bufEnv) {
          const fs = require('fs/promises')
          const fileContent = await fs.readFile('.env', 'utf8')
          const rows = fileContent.split(/\r?\n/)
          for (const row of rows) {
            const [key, value] = row.split('=', 2)
            if (key.trim() === 'BUF_REGISTRY_TOKEN') {
              bufEnv = value.trim()
            }
          }
        }

        if (bufEnv) {
          return `Bearer ${bufEnv}`
        }
        return currentHeader
      },
    },
  }),
}
```

#### yarnrc.yml (only relevant parts)

```yaml
npmScopes:
  buf:
    npmAlwaysAuth: true
    npmRegistryServer: "https://buf.build/gen/npm/v1/"

plugins:
  - ./.yarn/plugin-env-npm.js
```